# Redirecting to "http://domain-error.com"

Tags: networking, malware

I am being redirected to the website "http://domain-error.com". This is happening in Firefox, Chromium, Google chrome etc. I feel I am attacked by a virus or something similar to that.

[image: Firefox screenshot]

Update: the redirection happens quite frequently but, not always and is experiencing in all browser.

Firefox Add-ons Manager shows, "Ubuntu Modifications 3.2(Disabled)". Firefox Plug-ins shows "OpenH264 Video Codec provided by Cisco Systems, Inc.1.5.1". `/etc/hosts` is as follows:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   home-desktop

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

host google.com results as follows

```
home@home-desktop:~$ host google.com
google.com has address 216.58.220.14
google.com has IPv6 address 2404:6800:4009:804::200e
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
home@home-desktop:~$ host google.com
google.com has address 216.58.220.14
google.com has IPv6 address 2404:6800:4009:804::200e
google.com mail is handled by 20 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 40 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 30 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 50 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 10 aspmx.l.google.com.


home@home-desktop:~$ host google.com 8.8.8.8
Using domain server:
Name: 8.8.8.8
Address: 8.8.8.8#53
Aliases: 

google.com has address 216.58.196.14
google.com has IPv6 address 2404:6800:4009:805::200e
google.com mail is handled by 40 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 30 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 10 aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 20 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 50 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.
```

ClamTk Virus Scanner result as follows. But, after removing this virus reappears.

```
/home/home/.cache/mozilla/firefox/l5cuof0l.default/cache2/entries/74FFA44984EB1C9A25C368933E368C017D1BA402: PUA.Script.Packed-2 FOUND
/home/home/.cache/mozilla/firefox/l5cuof0l.default/cache2/entries/975E967B7FAAC093533721489F38B5558E903CD6: PUA.JS.Xored FOUND
/home/home/.cache/mozilla/firefox/l5cuof0l.default/cache2/entries/DC2B9FDFADA8ACF2A73587FB7C1363C96D865641: PUA.Script.Packed-2 FOUND
/home/home/.cache/mozilla/firefox/l5cuof0l.default/cache2/entries/D18ACE6C2F38228A99A6F24DEF604B65FE8EAD4D: PUA.Script.Packed-2 FOUND
/home/home/.cache/mozilla/firefox/l5cuof0l.default/cache2/entries/F0B2C1E21FAB8944116EE80787C026D0ACD117B3: PUA.Script.Packed-2 FOUND
/home/home/.cache/mozilla/firefox/l5cuof0l.default/cache2/entries/229277790D7F8A68B7983C1B74110047842CAB9F: PUA.Http.Exploit.CVE_2015_1692 FOUND
/home/home/.cache/mozilla/firefox/l5cuof0l.default/cache2/entries/3E710D766C56B38839F2FA8857831ED099BCE52A: PUA.JS.Xored FOUND
/home/home/.cache/mozilla/firefox/l5cuof0l.default/cache2/entries/10E466A6C5B7E8510DE813F537F27B186D75E2B6: PUA.Script.Packed-1 FOUND
/home/home/.cache/mozilla/firefox/l5cuof0l.default/cache2/entries/697815FD2C3AA32190D6EBEDC60695379DD6E754: PUA.Script.Packed-2 FOUND
/home/home/.cache/mozilla/firefox/l5cuof0l.default/cache2/entries/54B8B0B2368584CAC24E39B23E4493BEC8EC61D0: PUA.Http.Exploit.CVE_2015_1692 FOUND

----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
Known viruses: 4156276
Engine version: 0.98.7
Scanned directories: 392
Scanned files: 3020
Infected files: 10
Data scanned: 891.88 MB
Data read: 737.67 MB (ratio 1.21:1)
Time: 68.872 sec (1 m 8 s)
```

I was away ...
I feel this as BSNL phenomenon.  Today again The problem resurfaced. Now I have changed DNS server to openDNS... Hope this will solve the problem..
Thans for everybody for looking in to the problem.

Comment: Does this happen with every site you want to visit? Or only sites that do not exist?

Comment: Looks like some kind of search ad-ware has made its self your default notice even though the it claims to be Google the address is not Google and it is clearly advertising some sites to you, go to preferences >> search and see who your search provider is (Google by default)

Comment: I can load up the page for domain-error and it is not Google or an error, but some kind of search site http://domain-error.com/noresult.php

Comment: Your `hosts` file looks ok.

Comment: What's the output of `host google.com` and `host google.com 8.8.8.8`? Does this happen, when you start Firefox in safe mode or in other browsers?

Comment: The result of the DNS resolver shows, that the system networking settings are unaffected by whatever redirects your web browser requests. Now what about other browsers or Firefox running in safe mode? Are you still redirected? What are the network proxy settings of Firefox? Write me a comment with `@DavidFoerster` in it, to notify me of your update.

Comment: Exactly same thing is happening with me on Firefox on Ubuntu. This is happening on all google searches and even on opening some websites. I have checked that my browser has no malicious extension, but couldn't figure out how this thing got into my PC.

Comment: 4,156,276 viruses? You need to reinstall Ubuntu, dude.

Comment: PUA.* are not virus. The only one is PUA.Http.Exploit.CVE_2015_1692 and is a Windows virus. PUA stands for "Potentially Unwanted Application". Maybe this link will help you https://support.mozilla.org/it/questions/988500

Comment: Does this happen on other computers in the network as well? I had a case where the internet provider redirected to their "search" page every time they could't resolve an address.

Comment: I am having the same issue. I am using BSNL internet (India). Operating system Archlinux. Bowers Firefox. Other browsers doesn't seem to be effected.

Comment: Hi I am experiencing the same problem since two weeks, It happens for the domain that's dns is not resolved, probably the ones which are expired.  It happens on my tablets and phones too when connected to the same network. reset your modem and see what happens!! (you must know how to configure it )

Comment: There is a work around. You can put `::0 domain-error.com
::0   www.domain-error.com` in `/etc/hosts`

Comment: @user481684 Have you ever used any proxy service? VPN ?

Comment: check if you're using a proxy or vpn in your browser or through browser extensions. Also give us the DNS servers that are used by your router.  If we don't have all the right info, how do you expect us to help?
Ideally your DNS settings on the router are 8.8.8.8 (google) or opendns (208.67.222.222) or level3 (4.2.2.1). Your computers should point to your router.
But again, all that is irrelevant if you are using proxy or vpn. Don't rely on your ISP's DNS servers, they're often not as stable and less reliable.

Comment: Maybe your isp is redirecting your DNS traffic: http://www.ckollars.org/dns-intercepting.html
Could you set-up a VPN or use any proxy service?

Answer (score 14):

I am having this issue since a few days.

**The problems are:**

- Invalid domains are redirected to `domain-error.com`
- Some domains are redirected to `domain-error.com` multiple times but after a few attempts I could reach the website.

I have got the same problem in Ubuntu, Archlinux, Windows(7 and 10).
I am not saying that getting the same malware in all these operating system is impossible.

**But What is impossible** (nearly):
I downloaded a fresh copy of Ubuntu from the official website. Verified the [integrity](http://releases.ubuntu.com/trusty/) and live booted. Then I tried to reach an invalid URL.

Guess what happened!. I was again redirected to`http://domain-error.com/`

**So the problem is with the Internet Service Provider(ISP)?**

To confirm that I went to my friends apartment, who is using the same ISP and he is having the same problem.

I have blocked `domain-error.com` from loading (added entry to /etc/hosts) but the redirect still exist.

So I think that you are also having the same issue with the ISP.

**SOLUTION:**

Remove default DNS option from your router and set `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` as your DNS. It will work fine.

**Note**: My ISP is BSNL (India)

.

Comment: Did you try to contact your ISP?

Comment: Waiting for some days. May be they are working on it.

Comment: I contacted the ISP over phone. There is nothing they can do from there. It is programmed that way.

Comment: @IndrajithIndraprastham I am having the same problem. My ISP is also BSNL. I am on windows. Did you got any solution?

Comment: @HardikPatadia Yes there is a solution. Remove default DNS option from your router and set 8.8.8.8 an 8.8.4.4 as your DNS. It will work fine.

Comment: @IndrajithIndraprastham Thank you for the reply. I will try what you are saying. Do you mean I should go to my routers setting and do changes over there?

Answer (score 3):

Check your router configuration at 192.168.X.Y, login and look for DNS servers setup, I had once some joker changing my DNS servers on my router because of my weak admin password, these DNS servers were resolving about 1/3 of my traffic to a certain page loaded with ads, rest of the traffic was resolved correctly. Bad guys also use this technique for phishing.

Comment: I checked all the router settings but couldn't find anything suspicious.  Could it be something else?

Comment: @ParagGangil Try another computer on the same network, if same happens to that computer, problem may be router, ISP, someone in the middle. ... , but if problem is only on your computer, you can focus on how is DNS resolved on your system.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be what is known as ISP redirection, which is not uncommon. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISP_redirect_page for more information.  Quite a few ISP's have done this (I had it happen with Charter awhile back), and it's quite annoying.  What worked for me was setting alternate DNS servers as another poster mentioned.  You can also find how some others resolved it in the comments of this article: https://hackercodex.com/guide/how-to-stop-isp-dns-server-hijacking/

Answer (score 1):

At first, please check your extensions enabled in browser and let us know if you find anything suspicious. Then check your search providers. After that check

```
 /etc/hosts
```

for signs of a redirection.
Unfortunately Google does not have records which could clearly show cases similar to yours yet.

What did you do exactly before you started to experience this behaviour?

When I last time experienced something like that it was because of a tricky extension.

Armand

Comment: Well. I'd say, downvoting without any  comment is not the wisest thing I can imagine.
At that time when my comment was written the question was not well detailed, so there were the possibility for almost any type of 'attack'. Which ClamTK found as threat is a false positive, I'm sure. W/o any information I think no one can help. Whois shows hiren kakad as the domain owner (with an Axistel contact address). You can find his twitter profile then, which is full of spammy content. 

The most logical answer should be that OP mistyped URL then was redirected. We should know the prevalence in that.

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting an alternate DNS server in `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

The thing is that you are probably using DHCP, which will automatically assign a DNS server address to your computer. However, if your ISP's DNS server has been tampered with, it would be possible to do something like this. If this doesn't work, try using a VPN and see if that resolves the problem.

EDIT:
Your ISP is probably doing something to your DNS. I suggest you use a VPN or contact your ISP. Your account may be capped.
The real IPs for google.com

```
╰─ dig google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-9+deb8u3-Debian <<>> google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 55270
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 15, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.     299 IN  A   196.23.168.172
google.com.     299 IN  A   196.23.168.185
google.com.     299 IN  A   196.23.168.170
google.com.     299 IN  A   196.23.168.158
google.com.     299 IN  A   196.23.168.177
google.com.     299 IN  A   196.23.168.157
google.com.     299 IN  A   196.23.168.155
google.com.     299 IN  A   196.23.168.162
google.com.     299 IN  A   196.23.168.173
google.com.     299 IN  A   196.23.168.166
google.com.     299 IN  A   196.23.168.181
google.com.     299 IN  A   196.23.168.143
google.com.     299 IN  A   196.23.168.151
google.com.     299 IN  A   196.23.168.147
google.com.     299 IN  A   196.23.168.187

;; Query time: 190 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Fri Dec 18 10:48:53 SAST 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 279
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained by other answers, you problem is in DNS.  DNS protocol is vulnerable to various attacks.  The attacker does not have to be your ISP, it could be the router, anyone you share WiFi with, etc.

Therefore, it's highly recommended to use *DNSCrypt*, a better [DNS protocol](https://www.opendns.com/about/innovations/dnscrypt/).  Installation is quite simple.

```
sudo apt-get install dnscrypt-proxy
```

While you might want to use it together with an DNS cache for better performance.  I found instructions in [DNSCrypt ArchWiKi](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/DNSCrypt) quite helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a common browser settings exploit (possible done by the "Ubuntu Modifications 3.2" plugin). See this [article](http://computervirusremovalfixer.blogspot.se/2015/12/how-to-get-rid-of-httpdomain-errorcom.html). Try installing another browser and see if you get the same behavior. If not, you should completely reset your Firefox settings, which should fix it.